# Which one is faster? Hexapod or Quadruplets

Tags: hexapod

I am preparing for Trinity Firefighting Robot Contest America. and I need fast legged robot of the max size 30cm X 30cm X 30cm that use RX-24 servo  from Robotis.  The arena will be maze and perfectly flat. My robot upper body is perfectly symmetric so its  lower body or leg doesn't need to rotate its face to another direction but still need turn its motion for maneuver inside the maze.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to deal with such complexity as a legged robot ? Also note that typically those platform have a gait which impacts the sensors and needs to be addressed if you try to map the maze ... And lastly from experience legged robot are not as fast as small carts for equivalent power consumption

Comment: @N.Staub In the rule robot must have leg locomotion. The maze is almost static so I only need localization. I just need fast robot leg configuration.

Comment: And you need to buy it ready to assemble or you have some time for development ?

Comment: I can buy or assemble it. I just want to now which is faster in straight line. If you can suggest faster leg formation other than 4 or 6 plus its gait I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Hexapod robot with tripod gait cycle will be both more stable and faster in terms of the locomotion speed. It is more stable because the support polygon of the tripod gait is a triangle. But in return you have 6 more joints and hence 6 more servo motors, which increases the power consumption and the complexity of the system.